# Remove a tracking from a git branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a "feature/admin" branch that is tracking *multiple* branches (origin/feature/admin and development, the latter being local) - I want to remove the *local* tracking (so my local branch only tracks the remote branch origin/feature/admin).

I've tried removing it with git branch -dr development, but...

> > error: remote branch 'development' not found.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this little dilemma.

In the Git Config file of the repo, I deleted these two lines (using Gity):

Keys:

```
branch.feature/admin.remote
branch.feature/admin.merge
```

Values:

```
.
refs/heads/development
```

(respectively)

That removed the local tracking. I'm guessing the "." indicates local.

Answer (score 0):

The name "development" isn't a remote branch, since it doesn't include the name of a remote.  Take a look at the output of `git branch -a`:

```
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
```

The remote branches all start with the `remotes/` prefix.  So to delete the remote "develop" branch, I would run:

```
git branch -dr origin/develop
```

Although, having done this, the branch will come back next time I do a `git pull`.

Comment: I think that you mean 'the remote-tracking branch "develop"' instead of 'the branch remote "develop" branch'

Comment: @larsks As noted in the post, I wanted to delete the tracking of the _local_ branch, not the remote branch (since I tried git branch -dr _localbranch_ without success) - any advise on how to do the exact thing, but with local branches?

Comment: I believe I have described exactly what you want.  It preserves your local branch, but removes the tracking association with the remote branch.  For example, run `git show` to display tracking information, then `git branch -dr origin/develop`, and then run `git show` again, and you can see that the tracking association is no longer there.  This is only making changes in your local repository and has no effect on the remote repository.

Comment: @larsks The thing is that I don't want to remove the remote tracking, but the __local__ tracking. That's why in the example I put `git branch -dr development` - if I wanted to remove remote tracking, that would have worked, and your suggestion would have worked, too.